# Can I use links to Excel tables with paste special in Word?

Tags: excel, ms-word, word-field

I'm importing data from Excel table into Word 2013.

**Option 1.**
I select a range of cells, paste in Word as an Linking Excel Sheet.
The link in the field (after Alt + F9) looks like this:

```
{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Exps\\excel2word\\tmp.xlsx" "Sheet1!R1C1:R5C7" \a \p }
```

*Plus:* changes in the data are displayed in Word (after "Update Link").

*Minus:* when inserting a row, the Excel table spreads the formulas to the cells of the new row, but the row does not appear in Word. Similarly, when deleting a line.

**Option 2.**
I assign a name to a range of cells, select it, paste it into Word as an Linking Excel Sheet.
The link in the field (after Alt + F9) looks like this:

```
{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Exps\\excel2word\\tmp.xlsx" "Sheet1!NamedRange" \a \p }
```

*Plus:* data changes are displayed in Word ("Refresh Link").

*Plus:* when inserting a row, the Excel table spreads the formulas to the cells of the new row; in Word, the row appears. Similarly, when deleting a line.

*Minus:* it is required to name ranges additionally.

Maybe the name of a Excel table is equivalent to the names of named ranges? In any case, it is displayed along with them in the Name Manager.

It is logical to use ready-made names (Excel table), rather than creating new names for the same ranges.

From here
**Option 3.**
I correct the link from the named range to the Name of the Excel table, plus I tried all sorts of different options.
*Minus:* it does not work.

I used the following docs:

a) [Using structured references with Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)

b) [Insert, edit, and view fields in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-edit-and-view-fields-in-word-c429bbb0-8669-48a7-bd24-bab6ba6b06bb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

c) [Setting up links between a Word document and an Excel spreadsheet](https://golos.io/excel/@tdots/nastroika-svyazei-mezhdu-dokumentom-word-i-tablicei-excel)

In the last doc, it seems to be stated that they can do it, but really there is nothing.

**Question:**
Can I use the link to the Excel table and/or to its fragments - Headers, Data, Columns, Rows, Totals?

If so, how?

PS If this is not possible, then I will have to write code, but I would like to get by with formulas.

Comment: Now that you've corrected your original post, the question that needs to be answered is: why are you not simply using the existing Excel range names when copying/pasting? Unless they differ from the ranges you want to replicate, there is no reason you can't do that.

Comment: @macropod Here! This is the main question. In the Name Manager, there are only Tables names. There are no other named ranges. I do not want to do double work - assign new names to ranges that are already referenced by Tables names.
The second question is that if the Table names are not named ranges, then why are they are in the Name Manager. Since they are of a different nature, why not have a Manager for them?

Comment: "It is better to see once than to hear 100 times." I recorded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ueiFvymXS40) with a question. The video has subtitles in English. Maybe it will be so clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that it's not possible to use Excel Table names in Word's `Link` field. Word works only with SheetName!A1:A1 or Name Range range specifications.

I can't answer as to "why" or whether it will be supported in the future. I can speculate that the reason *might* be because Tables are a comparatively new feature in Excel that did not exist when the `Link` field was introduced. There may be other reasons - only the devs at Microsoft could say for sure.

If you look closely at the Name Manager in Excel you'll see that a different identifying symbol is at the left of Table entries than at the left of Range Name entries. The Table ranges cannot be altered within the Name Manager. So while Tables are listed here, they aren't managed in this interface and are definitely other "entities".

Comment: Yes, I did. Hopefully, in the future, the Word will be able to use structured references of Excel tables in the `Link`. Or the option to convert them to named ranges with one button.

Comment: @BorisBaublys UserVoice is the place to let Microsoft know what's missing in the Office applications. I find an entry for basically the same thing you're looking for: https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304924-word-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/33142663-link-to-structured-table-reference-in-excel You might want to upvote that and perhaps leave a comment if you have anything to add.